# Do I have to upgrade to 13.04 to use latest ATI driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, upgrade, ati

My question: Must we following the release each time it just comes out, to use latest application and drivers. Firstly I use Ubuntu on an old laptop and happy with it. I understand new release is better suitable for better HW, RAM etc; secondly on Ubuntu 11.10, 12.04, 12.10 there were issues I have spent a long time to fix for ATI driver, for internet connection etc. the speed result is still not better compared to 11.04.

No, I am not looking for any fix. I just want to know: I like to use latest graphic driver ATI on the desktop PC, can I stick with Ubuntu 11.04? How can I upgrade application security without moving up from the stable 11.04 Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 1):

You can not update 11.04 for security updates because it has reached EOL. Any update you make will have to be from the archive repositories and those are just updates up till the time 11.04 reached EOL so they are outdated and your system would still be vulnerable.

Here is a link that talks about EOL versions of ubuntu.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

I recommend 12.04 it will receive updates for five years and is the most stable version at this time.

You can edit your source list and be able to get updates but these will be old updates.
Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and change archive.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com

`sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Run the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and you should get the updates available.